# Renomear arquivo no python3

Tags: python-3.x

Por favor, alguém pode me ajudar?
Estou querendo renomear arquivos que têm caracteres no nome Ex. "123Pedro.jpg"
para "Pedro.jpg". Estava tentando usar str.translate(), mas não esta dando certo.
Valeu!!!

Comment: Vais percorrer uma pasta e ver um a um certo?

Comment: Tem algum pedaço de código que já tentou? Qual o erro que dá com o `str.translate()`?